# Copy/Paste formula from a cell into 18 rows of another column starting on next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

My formula is in M1.
I need to run a VBA that will copy that cell and paste it in Column G only but down 18 rows each time I run it and each time I run it, it starts in the next empty row in column G.

If I use record macro for doing it one time, this is what it looks like.

```
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=33
Range("G42:G59").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I know this isn't the best way and I am not this advanced in Excel.

Comment: I am missing one piece of my puzzle and i didn't realize it until today.....i need to add that when it paste the formula into those 18 cells, it then copies that same set of 18 cells and will paste it has values so it holds those values in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub Fred()
 dim r as range
 set r = range("G" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
 Range("M1").copy  r
 r.copy range(r.address & ":G" & r.row + 17)
 end sub
```

Comment: thank you.   the whole set didn't work but i used your range from "set r =" in the vba from the other answer in "name range" and it worked great!   thank again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs help with this also, both Harassed Dad and jakrooster where great and i pieced together their answers to get it to work.   Finish VBA i am using.

```
Sub Cash()

Dim rng_Copy As Range
Dim rng_Paste As Range

Set rng_Copy = Sheet1.Range("$M$1")
Set rng_Paste = Range("G" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

rng_Copy.Copy
rng_Paste.Resize(18, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd create a named range that returns the blank cell after the last filled cell in column G. So something like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$G:$G,MAX(2,IFERROR(MATCH(" *",Sheet1!$G:$G,-1),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+306,Sheet1!$G:$G,1),0))+1)
```

Then I'd use that named range in VBA to copy the formula in M1 and apply it to the next 18 rows.

```
Sub s_CopyPaste()

Dim rng_Copy As Range
Dim rng_Paste As Range

Set rng_Copy = Sheet1.Range("$M$1")
Set rng_Paste = Range("NAMED RANGE")

rng_Copy.Copy
rng_Paste.Resize(18, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas 'resize the blank cell to an 18x1 range

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks!  i kinda used both answers to piece together what works.

Comment: Sub Cash()

Dim rng_Copy As Range
Dim rng_Paste As Range

Set rng_Copy = Sheet1.Range("$M$1")
Set rng_Paste = Range("G" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

rng_Copy.Copy
rng_Paste.Resize(18, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End Sub